# Showing a view controller from a parallel window (with the same parent)

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am trying to show a ViewController directly from its sibling window, the tree looks kinds like this: CalibrationVC<--- MainVC ---> Settings VC. The MainVC presents the other two modally, and over current context. Now what I want to do is click a button in SettingsVC, that would open the CalibrationVC for a specific device. I have managed to do so using unwind segues and a delegate from the SettingsVC, and it looks like this:

```
- (void)showViewForDeviceCalibration
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCalibrationViewFromSettings" sender:nil];
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCalibrationViewFromSettings"])
    {
        [_delegate calibrateDevice:deviceToConfigure];
    }
}
```

The delegate implementation:

```
-(void)calibrateDevice:(Device *)device
{
    dispatch_block_t autoinitService =
    ^{
        deviceToCalibrateFromSettings = device;
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCalibrationViewForDeviceFromSettings" sender:nil];
        });

    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0), autoinitService);
}
```

And the prepare for segue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id) sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCalibrationViewForDeviceFromSettings"])
    {
        CalibrationViewController *destinationController = (CalibrationViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSArray *devicesToCalibrate = [NSArray arrayWithObject:deviceToCalibrateFromSettings];
        [destinationController setDevicesToCalibrate: devicesToCalibrate];
}
```

This works well, but is there a better way to do that? I am really concerned about the delegate implementation because it uses a separate thread only to wait for a moment and then use the main thread again. I had to do this because without it the CalibrationVC would not appear saying that the MainVC is already presenting. So to sum thing up, is there a better, more optimal/proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specifically need unwind segues, you could do something like this:

Settings VC:

```
- (void)showViewForDeviceCalibration
{
    [_delegate calibrateDevice:deviceToConfigure];
}
```

Delegate:

```
-(void)calibrateDevice:(Device *)device 
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCalibrationViewForDeviceFromSettings" sender:nil];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank You, this is exactly what i was looking for, clear and simple.